# Closed form for an integral

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I am trying to find a closed form for this integral:

$\int\limits_{a}^{\infty} \exp(-\frac{b}{x})\exp(-cx)dx$

where a,b,c, are positive constants.
Does anyone have any suggestions or can advise?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have:
$$ \mathcal{L}\left(e^{-1/x}\right)= \frac{2}{\sqrt{s}}\,K_1(2\sqrt{s}) $$
where $K_1$ is a [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html).

Your integral is so an "*incomplete modified Bessel function of the second kind*", not very nice or elementary. Anyway,

$$I(a,b,c)=\int_{a}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\frac{b+cx^2}{x}\right)\,dx = \sqrt\frac{b}{c}\int_{a\sqrt\frac{c}{b}}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-\sqrt{bc}\,\frac{1+x^2}{x}\right)\,dx$$
so by defining
$$ J(u,v) = \int_{u}^{+\infty}\exp\left(-v\cdot\frac{1+x^2}{2x}\right)\,dx \tag{1}$$
we have:
$$ I(a,b,c) = \sqrt\frac{b}{c}\,J\left(a\sqrt\frac{c}{b},2\sqrt{bc}\right). $$
Assuming $u\gg 1$, we have:
$$ J(u,v)\approx \int_{u}^{+\infty}e^{-vx/2}\,dx = \frac{2}{v} e^{-\frac{uv}{2}}\tag{2}$$
hence if $a\sqrt\frac{c}{b}$ is large,
$$ I(a,b,c)\approx \frac{1}{c}e^{-ac}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: +1 and I guess $\mathcal L$ is the laplace transform?

Comment: @Ant: yes, sure.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Do you have any reference about "incomplete modified Bessel function of the second kind"? actually, I need some asymptotic approximations of this integral.

Comment: @Mahdi: I added some lines to explain how to approximate your integral.